# Filling in gaps in pandas with averages of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series data where the correlations are strong across columns and there are missing observations.  So I fill in the gaps using the observations that are present.   The code works, but I'm looping through each cell in a clumsy fashion.   Can someone perform this calc pythonically?  Working code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1,2,3,4,5,np.nan,7,8,9]
df['B'] = [7,9,np.nan,13,15,17,19,21,23]
df['C'] = [-5,0,5,10,np.nan,20,25,30,35]


print(df)

colstd = df.std(axis=0)
rowstd = df.std(axis=1)
colavg = df.mean(axis=0)
rowavg = df.mean(axis=1)

for idx , row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        if pd.isna(df.loc[idx][col]):
            df.loc[idx][col] = colavg[col] +  colstd[col] * np.nanmean((row - colavg)/colstd)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same as vectorial operations. There might be a simpler way, I just tried to follow your logic:

```
colstd = df.std(axis=0)
rowstd = df.std(axis=1)
colavg = df.mean(axis=0)
rowavg = df.mean(axis=1)
fill = colavg.values+colstd.values*np.array([df.sub(colavg).div(colstd).mean(axis=1).values]*3).T
df.where(~df.isna(), fill)
```

output:

```
          A          B          C
0  1.000000   7.000000  -5.000000
1  2.000000   9.000000   0.000000
2  3.000000  11.755997   5.000000
3  4.000000  13.000000  10.000000
4  5.000000  15.000000  14.665627
5  5.756524  17.000000  20.000000
6  7.000000  19.000000  25.000000
7  8.000000  21.000000  30.000000
8  9.000000  23.000000  35.000000
```

*NB. I had not seen this transformation before, can you give details about it?*

Comment: I've not seen it before either, but it seems reasonable to me.   
I am simply filling in missing values with the "averages" of the other columns, where the averages are normalized.  To take it a step further, after filling in the missing values, 
 you could recreate each hole and refill it using the new averages including the filled data.   IF you repeat that, I think in my simple example it will converge to the 'correct' values of 6, 11, and 15.

Comment: If you use `df.interpolate()`, you'll get 6,11,15 directly, no need to use the values of other columns

Comment: Yes, but that's an artifact of the data being in order and having a correlation of 1.0.   Typically the correlations aren't 1.0 across the columns and you can't order the columns, so interpolate is the wrong idea.   It's my fault for using such a contrived example dataset.  If you shuffle the rows, you'll see the interpolate doesn't behave but the method I use should produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill with mean, use this

```
df.fillna(df.mean(axis=0))
```

Comment: This is not the operation that OP want, the output with your proposed answer is incorrect

Comment: The fill value computation is more complex than this in the op

Comment: required computation can be placed within the df.fillna(). I was suggesting sample for it. I have mentioned in the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DataFrame.apply` with a lambda function, the idea is to avoid manual iteration of the dataframe i.e. `iterrows()`:

```py
(df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([colavg[col] +  
                                   colstd[col] * 
                                   np.nanmean((row - colavg)/colstd) 
                                   if pd.isna(row[col]) 
                                   else row[col] for col in row.index],index=row.index), 
          axis=1))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
          A          B          C
0  1.000000   7.000000  -5.000000
1  2.000000   9.000000   0.000000
2  3.000000  11.755997   5.000000
3  4.000000  13.000000  10.000000
4  5.000000  15.000000  14.665627
5  5.756524  17.000000  20.000000
6  7.000000  19.000000  25.000000
7  8.000000  21.000000  30.000000
8  9.000000  23.000000  35.000000
```

Here is the time comparison for the executions:

```py
%%timeit
for idx , row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        if pd.isna(x.loc[idx][col]):
            df.loc[idx][col] = colavg[col] +  colstd[col] * np.nanmean((row - colavg)/colstd)
```

```py
5.39 ms ± 401 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
x=(df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([colavg[col] +  
                                   colstd[col] * 
                                   np.nanmean((row - colavg)/colstd) 
                                   if pd.isna(row[col]) 
                                   else row[col] for col in row.index],index=row.index), 
          axis=1))
```

```py
2.68 ms ± 398 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @HenryEcker, for `NaN` comparison `pd.isna(x.loc[idx][col])`, variable `x` has been used which is essentially a copy of the dataframe. Similaryly, in the second case, `df` is recreated before running the code.

Comment: Some of those details about how to run the test code might be good to include with your timing information. But thank you for the clarifications.